# Keeping track of head of ListNode in Java

Tags: java, head

I am currently working on my own Java class called LString, which is meant to convert back and forth between linked lists of characters and Strings.

I am having issues with my toString() method, specifically keeping track of the "head" of the linked list in order to loop through it and concatenate the characters into a new string. While researching, I read that I am supposed to keep track of the head of the list somehow, but I can't figure out how to implement it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: The error message I am receiving is:

LString.java:79: error: cannot find symbol
      ListNode current = this.front;

```
public class LString{


   private static int length;
   // ListNode constructors

   // Creates a new ListNode with characters stored in variable "data" and 
   // Node named next
   private class ListNode{
      char item;
      ListNode next;


      private ListNode(){
      }

      // creates a new ListNode that has the value and links to the specified ListNode
      private ListNode(char item, ListNode next){
         this.item = item;
         this.next = next;
      }

      // given a character, creates a new ListNode that doesn't link to anything
      private ListNode(char item){
         this.item = item;
         this.next = null;
      }


   }


   public LString(){
      this.length = 0;
      ListNode front = new ListNode();
   }

   //LString
   // Takes in a String object and loops until it has added all characters to a new linked list
   public LString(String original){

      ListNode front;
      this.length = 1;                           // length keeps track of number of nodes

      if (original.charAt(0) == 0){             // creates a new ListNode if it is an empty string
         front = new ListNode();       
      }
      else {
         front = new ListNode(original.charAt(0));
      }


      //System.out.println("this is happening " + front.item);

      //ListNode current = front;  
      for (int index = 1; index < original.length(); index++) {
         front.next = new ListNode(original.charAt(index), front.next);
         front = front.next;
         //System.out.println("strings: " + front.item);
         length++;
      }
         //System.out.println("length: " + length);
   }

   // returns length of the LString object
   public int length(){
      return this.length;
   }

   // toString takes an LString object and converts it to a string
   public String toString(){
      StringBuilder newString;

      ListNode current = this.front;
      while (current.next != null){
         newString.append(current.item);
         current = current.next; 
      }

      return newString.toString();
   }

   public static void main(String[] args){
      LString stuffTest = new LString("hello");
      int valueOf = stuffTest.length();
      System.out.println(stuffTest.length());
      String testMeWhy = stuffTest.toString();

   }





}
```

Comment: As your question stands now, we will have to actually debug your code to find out what is wrong.  Are you getting any error output or can you give a specific problem?

Comment: Your test for an empty string is wrong.  If the string is empty, `original.charAt(0) == 0` will throw an exception because there is no character at index 0.  Are you thinking in C?  Try `original.isEmpty()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general pattern for building a linked list by appending to the end is:

At the beginning:

```
head = null;
tail = null;
```

To append `newNode` to the list:

```
if (head == null) {
    head = newNode;
} else {
    tail.next = newNode;
}
tail = newNode;
```

I think you're trying to do this by keeping just one pointer in the list class, which doesn't work very well.  Also, doing things using this pattern means you don't have to have a "special" node at the front of the list, unless there's some other good reason to.  It looks like you were trying to use `new ListNode()` with no arguments to create some kind of special node, but only sometimes.  It's unnecessary and just makes things more complicated.

Comment: nice and succinct :)

Answer (score 0):

Your basic problem is that there should be only one `front`, and it should be a class member and not a local variable. That is how your `LString` class "keeps track" of the first node.

```
public class LString {
    private ListNode front = null;
    private int size = 0;
    ...
```

This will get you started and allow you to maintain the actual list.  Your other `LString` methods will also need some work, but once you get past this problem you should be able to use your debugger to step through the code and solve the remaining issues yourself.